# Show me an example between topology and sigma-algebra

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Like the title of topic, could you give me an example, which show the different between Topology (on set) and $\sigma$-algebra?

Further more, could you tell me what is the application of topology (on set)?

Comment: There are two possible $\sigma$-algebras on a set with two elements, but four possible topologies.

Answer (score 1):

They have different axioms, though with a similar flavour. Topologies are closed under *arbitrary* (not just countable) unions, but are only closed under *finite* (again, not countable) intersections. Topologies also are not closed under complements, unlike $\sigma$-algebras.

As an example, the Borel sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, which contains the topology (i.e. all open sets). However, unlike the topology (in general) it will also contain all closed sets, and many other sets. As a more specific example, the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$ will include the half-open interval $[0, 1)$, which is not in the topology.